# Reading XML nodes with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml

I have a trouble reading from XML file using LINQ.

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Name Type="First">Jack</Name>
    <Name Type="Last">Black</Name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name Type="First">John</Name>
    <Name Type="Last">Blue</Name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name Type="First">Dan</Name>
    <Name Type="Last">Red</Name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name Type="First">Patrick</Name>
    <Name Type="Last">Green</Name>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

The code I am using is following

```
    XElement doc = XElement.Load("xmldoc.xml");
    var query = from x in doc.Elements("Employee") where x.Element("Name").Attribute("Type").Value == "First" select x;
    foreach (XElement item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Element("Name").Value);
    }
```

This code returns me all first names but when i change attribute value from first to last it comes blank.

When i switch name nodes it retuns last names. For me it looks like for each employe query returns values from first name node and ignoring the second one. Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: Do you really want `Employee` elements in your query result, or just the names?  If you just want names, then you need to be selecting from the names, not from the employees.  Otherwise, you'll need to transform the result (e.g., XPath) to filter out the tags you don't want.  Or you could simply have left off the `where` altogether and grabbed the tag you wanted in your `foreach`: `Console.WriteLine(item.Elements("Name").Single (i => i.Attribute("Type").Value == "Last").Value);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `x.Element("Name")` call will return the first `Name` element. You actually need to query all the `Name` elements and filter for the one with the `Last` attribute value.

Try this instead:

```
var query = from x in doc.Elements("Employee").Elements("Name")
            where x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Last"
            select x;

foreach (XElement item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm but there was 1 small issue.
Your code works only if i use XDocument to open XML file instead of XElement.

Comment: @user2847238 right, I was using an `XDocument` so I had added the `Root` property. I realized you were using an `XElement` so it isn't needed. I updated the post and it should be fine now.